# How to receive email notification of new Facebook messages in 2020?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I would like to receive email notifications for facebook messages if I don't read them.

Previously I was getting email for unread chats/messages

However I accidentally clicked on unsubscribe link in the email. Now I am unable to find the option to enable it in the settings.

Please help!

I have searched old thrreads but they're outdated and there's no longer an  option